# Import classes conditionally with Spring Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have to import classes conditionally in my Configuration class of Spring. So there are 3 Configuration classes with `@Configuration` annotation:

```
@Configuration
public SubClass1 {
   ...
}

@Configuration
public SubClass2 {
   ...
}

@Configuration
// something like this: @Import(if (flag) 'SubClass1.class' else 'SubClass2.class')
public MainClass1 {
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to import classes conditionally by `@import` annotation? Or will I have to import all the classes?

Answer (score 1):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html?is-external=true), the `value` element of the `@Import` annotation must be an array of `Class` objects.

```
value

public abstract Class<?>[] value

The @Configuration, ImportSelector 
and/or ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar classes to import.
```

Therefore, you cannot create SpEL statements to conditionally import resources using the `@Import` annotation.

The closest you can get to the conditional imports of resources is to use [Profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/).