# Applying logic to Spring @Import annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Is it possible to apply logic to the @Import annotation for Spring config? I want to import certain child spring classes depending on some conditions. There'll only ever be one class imported, but it could be one of several different classes depending on some conditions.

```
@Configuration
@Import(getChildClass())

public Class<? extends SpringConfiguration> getChildClass { return FooSpringConfiguration }
```

was my attempt at getting it to work. The compiler complains saying that the value of import must be a class literal.

Any idea?

Comment: Which kind of conditions? Properties values?

Comment: Yeah, properties values.

Answer (score 1):

As said in this other StackOverflow post [Import classes conditionally with Spring Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193243/import-classes-conditionally-with-spring-annotation) the @Import annotation asks for a class array, so you cannot achieve this functionality.

If you need to create beans based on some logic, you can use FactoryBeans to instantiate your beans with a Prototype scope, so every time they are being instantiated you can apply the control in the Factory bean method. This has some restrictions.

Other possible way of achieving this is using profiles (but this also has some restrictions).

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those options.